# Excel: one column has duplicates of each value, I need to take averages of the corresponding two values from the other columns

Tags: excel-2007

Example:

```
column A column B
A         1
A         2
B         2
B         2
C         1
C         1
```

I would somehow like to get the following result:

```
column A column B
A        1.5
B        2
C        1
```

(which are averages of 1 and 2, 2 and 2 and 1 and 1)
How do I achieve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Excel 2007 or above, you can also use the shorter AVERAGEIF function:

```
=AVERAGEIF($A$1:$A:$6,D1,$B$1:$B$6)
```

Less typing, easier to read..

Answer (score 0):

In D1:D3, type A, B, C.  Then in E1, put this formula

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$6,D1,$B$1:$B$6)/COUNTIF($A$1:$A$6,D1)
```

and fill down to E3.  If you want to replace the existing data, copy E1:E3 and paste-special-values over itself.  Then delete A:C.

Alternatively, you can add headers to your data, say "Letter" and "Number".  Then create a Pivot Table from your data.  Put Letter in the rows section and Number in the Data section.  Change your Data section from SUM to AVERAGE and you'll get the same result.